# Import Dataframe to Firebase-admin

Tags: python-3.x, firebase-admin

I am new to python backend development and working on a small project to improve my skills.

I am working on analyzing the data (correlation, description function, etc.)
So, my outputs will be matrix or dictionaries, and I want to display the results on a web using angular (later).

I managed to connect to my firebase database using the following commands

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
```

But now I am struggling, and don't know how to export my outputs (dict, list, dataframes) to Firebase DB.
For example:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
description = A.describe()
```

I want to push "description" to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how to create document references, and save data to them using the Python API:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

```
data = A.to_dict()[0]
print(data) # {'count': 3.0, 'mean': 2.0, 'std': 1.0, ...
db.collection(u'MyCollection').document(u'MyDocument').set(data)
```

Comment: How do I import with orient as records? Because it returns a list which can't be set/import to firestore.