# Importing data from firestore to python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I need to transfer some collections from firestore to pandas dataframe for analysis ans have some problems

Method from firebase docs :

docs = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).stream()

```
for doc in docs:
    print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```

my collection contains 100k elements, and when iterator at loop is near 50k i receive an error :

```
'_UnaryStreamMultiCallable' object has no attribute '_retry'
```

I load only one collection, wout parallel downloads

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [link_1](https://gist.github.com/romicofre/ee80100b62b5fdbed42218e8239df94e) and [link_2](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/pandas/firestore-to-pandas-dataframe/), you can check for the syntax of importing collections from firestore to pandas dataframe.

> Example 1 :
>
> ```
> import pandas as pd
>
> ref = db.collection(u'user')
> docs = ref.stream()
>
> items = list(map(lambda x: {**x.to_dict(), 'id': x.id}, docs))
>
> df = pd.DataFrame(items) # , columns=['id', 'email']
> df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
> ```
>
> Example 2:
>
> ```
> import pandas as pd
> from google.cloud import firestore
>
> db = firestore.Client()
> users = list(db.collection(u'users').stream())
>
> users_dict = list(map(lambda x: x.to_dict(), users))
> df = pd.DataFrame(users_dict)
> ```

For more information, You can refer to the Stackoverflow [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57549026/15774176) and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59880588/15774176):

Comment: Thanks, I tried both methods, but the error is still exist

Comment: can you check this error : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65326840/15774176 is it helpful?